# Is PHP absolutely necessary to make a contact form?

Tags: php, css, html, contact-form

I'm writing up my first website and I am down to the last part; the contact form. Everything has been just HTML5 and CSS so far. From the searches I've done online it would seem that PHP is necessary to make contact forms. Is that true? If not what are some other ways? I'm guess making a contact form with just HTML5 and CSS isn't possible.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: well there is the old html **mailto** if you cant use php

Answer (score 3):

> Is PHP absolutely necessary to make a contact form?

PHP, no. A server side scripting language of some description, yes.

PHP is generally used because it's common and is shipped with most standard web servers.

You could also use ASP, Python, node.js, whatever you want.

> I'm guess making a contact form with just HTML5 and CSS isn't possible.

Making the form is, you just won't be able to send any emails without it.

---

The only way you could achieve this without using your own server side validation is to use someone else's (i.e. a third party to send your email for you). You'll still be exposing your connection to them, which isn't ideal.

Just add it with PHP if your web server has it installed already! [See the documentation for examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). Otherwise there's plenty of tutorials online if you search "*[language here]* contact form tutorial".

Answer (score 2):

No, PHP is not necessary. To make a contact form which a user can send you'll need  some kind of a server-side implementation, and PHP is one of the easiest ways to go.

But you are correct in that HTML and CSS wont be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could send an email directly from the user's device to your email address using javascript like this

`window.open('mailto:oliver@example.com?subject=subject&body=body');`

the subject and body could be made from the form content. When you receive the email, you do what you want with it.

Comment: This is only works if the user have a mail client installed and set up on their device. It won't work for all the people that are using web mail services like gmail and such, like many do.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson actually you can set up most browsers to use gmail etc for maito links

Comment: Sure, are you going to have a guide for all the users on how to do that for their respective browser and service? That will most likely drop your conversion rate quite quickly. Plus, people aren't always on their own computers.